# React: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-project-moviedb-api-zeqk4?fontsize=14).

**What I'm trying to do:**

Trying to have the list of movies display, when fetched with Axios, to the area on the right of the app.

I'm not sure if this is a passing prop issue, or if it's something else. Any hints as to what's going on?

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

import "../Movie/_movie.scss";

const Movie = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <h3>Movies should show up here</h3>
            <ul>
              {props.movies.map(movie => (
                <li key={movie.id}>
                  <img
                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${movie.poster_path}`}
                  />
                  <h3>{movie.original_title}</h3>
                  <p>Date: {movie.release_date}</p>{" "}
                  <p>Rating: {movie.vote_average}/10</p>
                  <p>{movie.overview}</p>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

Comment: [`Movie.defaultProps = { movies: [] };`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops)

Comment: Why don't you write tests to figure out the issue, you can pass in props of varying types and see how your component behaves with each?

Comment: How do you render this component ?

Answer (score 2):

What's most likely happening is your `render` function is running before the api call has had time to complete, thus `props.movies` is `undefined` at the time when `render` needs it. What you can do is either give `props.movies` a default value of 
an empty array `[]` or you can first check to see if `props.movies` is defined before mapping by doing `props.movies && props.movies.map`.

Answer (score 0):

While accessing movies object add check `props.movies && props.movies.map(movie=>`

Comment: `const Movie = props => {` <-- why would they use this?

Comment: It used for block of statement